# Сортировка по параметрам из другой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, сортировка

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать следующее?
Хотел отсортировать статьи по рейтингу, рейтинг насчитывается через этот модуль https://github.com/hauntd/yii2-vote.
Что-то вроде этого, только views это поле из таблицы со статьями, а мне нужно 
сортировать по полю из таблицы с рейтингом:

```
<?php usort($competition, function ($a, $b) {
            return ($b['views'] - $a['views']);
        }) ?>
        <?php foreach ($competition as $item1): ?>
        ...
```

Связал модели, попробовал вот так:

```
<?php usort($competition, function ($a, $b) {
            return ($b->aggregate['rating'] - $a->aggregate['rating']);
        }) ?>
        <?php foreach ($competition as $item1): ?>
        ...
```

Порядок статей меняется, но не так как хотелось бы.

Comment: а как хотелось, и как меняется? Если в другую сторону развернуть надо, то `$b` с `$a` местами поменяйте

Comment: @teran сейчас по просмотрам сортирует, нормально http://joxi.ru/brRjnNQtPYLLr1 , если сделать как во втором примере получается вот так http://joxi.ru/Dr819w4TazJlm6 , пост с самым большим рейтингом не первый и перед ним идут те, у которых вообще его нет.